# Is there a way to fill select element with datalist

Tags: html

For `input` element we can use `datalist` element as autocomplete

```
<input name="account" placeholder="account" list="publisher">

<datalist id="publisher">
  <option value="00000" >00000</option>
  <option value="00001" >00001</option>
  <option value="00002">00002</option>
</datalist>
```

there is a way to do so for `select` element ?  not autocomplete just fill the select with options for example:

```
the two example should be equivalent
<select name=account>
  <option value="00000" >00000</option>
  <option value="00001" >00001</option>
  <option value="00002">00002</option>
</select>
and that 
<select name="account" list="publisher"></select>
```

Comment: Are you asking for a `select` with autocomplete?

Comment: nop, some selects in my simple page that each one use the same data, thanks i edit my qustion

Comment: so you basically mean a placeholder for date? should `<input name="account">` fetch data from it?

Comment: I update my question again